# How can All Might live without his stomach?

Tags: my-hero-academia

In the anime All Might tells in a fight half of his respiratory organs were destroyed and he lost his complete stomach. How can All  Might live without his stomach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Living without a stomach isn't as impossible and absurd as it first sounds as removing the entire stomach is currently one of the more common treatments for stomach cancer too.

You can find a short explanation how part of the small intestine turns into something like a pouch to take over the role of the stomach in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRqUJy_xFY8), while there are numerous articles written by doctors, patients and their relatives on the internet.

Just linking the first few hits Google dropped for me:

[Life Without a Stomach](https://www.nostomachforcancer.org/about/life-without-a-stomach)

[How to live without a stomach](https://www.nostomachforcancer.org/news/blog/167-how-to-live-without-a-stomach)

[Can You Live Without A Stomach?](https://www.scienceabc.com/humans/can-you-live-without-a-stomach.html)

[One man’s choice: Life without a stomach, or dying from stomach cancer?](https://www.washingtonpost.com/local/one-mans-choice-life-without-a-stomach-or-dying-from-stomach-cancer/2017/12/27/f2c05928-ce13-11e7-a1a3-0d1e45a6de3d_story.html?utm_term=.da6fc27cbdda)